# Change values dynamically in an associative array

Tags: php

I want to replace the values of some keys dynamically at the final iteration of the foreach loop `i.e. from [color] => 'grey' to [color] => 'green'`.

Here is the actual script

```
<?php
$line = "After six months, participants in both vitamin D supplementation groups had lost more weight and had greater reductions in their waistlines than those who hadn't taken the supplements, Vigna's team said";
// $chunks = str_split($line, 35);
$array = explode("\n", wordwrap($line, 40, "\n"));
// echo '<pre>' . print_r($chunks, true);

    function splitTextString($array) 
    {
         foreach($array as $key=>$value) 
         {
            $linesArr{$key}['name'] = $value;
            $linesArr{$key}['font-size'] = 27;
            $linesArr{$key}['color'] = "grey";
        }
                return $linesArr;
    }


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(splitTextString($array));
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: And where is the problem now?

Comment: Would like to change color value i.e. "grey" to "green" at the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the string in the last iteration

```
<?php

    $line  = "After six months ...";
    $array = explode("\n", wordwrap($line, 40, "\n"));

    function splitTextString($array) {

         end($array);
         $last = key($array);
         reset($array);

         foreach($array as $key=>$value) {

            $color = $key === $last ? "green" : "grey";

            $linesArr{$key}['name'] = $value;
            $linesArr{$key}['font-size'] = 27;
            $linesArr{$key}['color'] = $color;
        }

        return $linesArr;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(splitTextString($array));
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: `end()` takes the array by reference and sets the array pointer to the last element. I would more `count()` the array before the foreach loop and then check with the key if it is the last element.

Comment: @ Rizier123 Ok, got it.

Comment: @Rizier123 - I can change it to cache the last key, and check unique keys instead, if that makes you happier? Should also avoid issues with duplicate values in the array